# Kotlin - Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm Still beginner in android app so when I'm trying to build this app I get the following error in the Log:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-31:19 to override.
```

and the build.grade file had this dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

I try to google a solution but nothing find out.

Comment: Read the suggestion in the error you posted.

Comment: @TheWanderer  I try it but It's give to mush error

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Explanation: some of the dependencies, for example com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0, use Android X. [Jetifier](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) is required to use android.support.* classes in Android X, as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: Yes but I fix it

Answer (score 0):

我也记录一下
再本人的设备上，是由于 androidx 和android support 不兼容导致。

删除项目所有androidx的方法，或者使用上面那个人说的。
查看当前项目是否引用androidx相关的库， 请再terminal 里面执行 gradlew :app:dependencies >1.txt 然后查看是否有androidx 的关键字，然后把相应的导入库也成支持的即可。

Comment: On Stack Overflow, all answers must be in English. Please [edit] your answer and translate it to English. Otherwise, it will get removed.